# Check a filtered table for specific data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form (frm_Property) that shows information for a property and within that form another form (frm_Rate) that is a filtered table that displays all rates associated with that property. I want to check the filtered rate table to make sure that there are either no rates entered or there is a current rate (ie the current date falls between the start and end date of a rate). If there is no current rate (only with other rates entered) I want to stop the close of the form and a message box to open telling the user to enter a current rate.

After searching and complying many different things, this is the code that I have currently.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim currdate, check As String

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Rate WHERE Property = " & Me.Property)
currdate = Date


'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    'Check if rate is current rate
    If currdate >= [tbl_rate.Start_Date] And currdat <= [tbl_rate.End_Date] Then
        check = "Good"
    Exit Do
    Else
    'Move to the next record.
        check = "Bad"
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
MsgBox check 'testing to see if correctly identified if current rate exists
Else
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

If check = "Bad" Then
MsgBox "Please enter current rate."
Cancel = True
End If

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up


End Sub
```

Currently it can detect if no record is entered, but it always tells me that there is no current rate even if there is and I am not sure why.

I also have this code located within frm_rate. I don't know if that is why I am having difficulty stopping the form from closing. I was reading about on unload stopping the form from closing which is why I chose that one. I suspect I am having trouble because my "On Unload" is in the subform.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unload event for subform occurs after Unload of main form, so the code in subform is useless. In main form you need to save the data first `Me.Dirty = false` After this your code will be able to see new data in table. Also you can use `RecordsetClone` property of subform for accessing the data in in subform.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reponse as I don't get to work on this as often as I would like. I moved the code to the main form and added me.dirty=false above Set rs = Me.frm_RateEdit.Form.RecordsetClone (which I change based on your suggestion). I run into an error 2465 (debugs at If currdate...) and have not been able to figure it out after searching it online. It might have to do with the fact that the date fields are on the subform. To be honest, I do not have more time today or this week to work with it but I was hoping you might be able to help steer me more in the correct direction again.

Comment: I'm quite sure that 2465 in your case means that Access cannot find a property, field or method you referenced. In your case row should be: `If currdate >= rs![Start_Date] And currdate <= rs![End_Date] Then`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I did run into one more issue with my close button, but I added an Error Handler to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RecordsetClone` of the subform and `FindFirst`:

```
Dim currdate As String
Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformCONTROL.Form.RecordsetClone

' Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows.
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    check = "Empty"
Else
    ' Check if rate is current rate.
    currdate = Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd"
    rs.FindFirst "#" & currdate "# Between tbl_rate.Start_Date And tbl_rate.End_Date"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        check = "Good"
    Else
        check = "Bad"
    End If
End If
```